# Client not connecting to server the second time in a loop

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a small server - client application in Python 2.7
The client is supposed to get data from the server.
Here is the code for the clint

```
def main(ThreadNmber):

    queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=25000)
    try:
        for i in range(ThreadNmber):
            t = Downloader(queue)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
    except Exception, e:
        return 1
    while 1:
        s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        print 'Connecting'
        s2.connect((HOST, PORT))
        print 'Receiving data...'
        data = s2.recv(99950)
        s2.close()
        if 'empty' in data:
            time.sleep(300)
        else:
            for line in data.split('*'):
                try:
                    a = line.split(' ')[0]
                    b = line.split(' ')[1]
                    c = line.split(' ')[2]
                    queue.put((a.rstrip(),b.rstrip(),c.rstrip()))

                except:
                    pass
```

And this is for the server:

```
HOST = ''                
PORT = 31337              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)
while 1:
tuple = ''
conn, addr = s.accept()
while 1:
    try:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print str(addr)+' Said '+data
    except:
        conn.close()
        break

    if queue.qsize() > 20000:
        x = 20000
    else:
        x = queue.qsize()

    if x == 0:
        tuple = "Queue empty, come back another time"
        conn.sendall(tuple)
        conn.close()
        print str(addr)+' Said '+data+
        break
    for i in range(x):
        a,b,c = queue.get()
        tuple += a+' '+b+' '+c+'*'

    try:
        conn.sendall(tuple)
        conn.close()
        print str(addr)+' Said '+data+'. I served him well'
        break
    except:
        conn.close()
        break
```

My problem is that, the client,when working in the While loop,  after it successfully connects the first time, when it gets to the second time, it just hands on "Connecting", not being able to connect to the server again.

The funny part is that, when I am testing with the client without any work involved, just getting data and closing, it works fine.

In the client side, I am also doing socket work in the threads. After doing some tests, I found out that, when I cut that part out, e.g. no other socket work going on, the client works fine, no problems whatsoever.

Any thoughts on what the problem would be ?
I am using sendall because data is large ( around 400-500kb ) if someone wonders why.

Comment: I can't understand how the client can work the first time: the server is not sending anything, whereas the client is waiting for data in a recv() call... Both are in recv. Is it really your real code?

Comment: Kindly use the gadgets called eyes and observe the part where it says conn.sendall(tuple) in the server code. Thanks )

Comment: What I see with my poor eyes is that you're doing accept, then recv in your server ; your client is doing connect then recv. For me it's a dead end. Server or client should send something before. Maybe the code you have pasted here is not exactly what you're executing, then?